# bootstrap model passed text appear as raw text and not html (example </br> shows up instead of a new line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on this bootstrap modal right now, but ran into a problem..

[image: html tags bootstrap jquery]

for the modal, I pass the modal data using jquery like this

```
<script>
$(function()
{
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) 
    {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
        offer = button.data('offer');
        modal.find('.modal-body .placeoffer h5').text(offer);
    });
});
</script>
```

It gets compensated in the div like this

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <style>.close {position:absolute;top:10;left:10;}</style>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="placeoffer"><h5 align="right"></h5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now my question is, I send the offer text with html tags, but instead of rendering the html tags, they show up as raw data, how can I make them get parsed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try html(offer) instead of text(offer)

\o/